# Вопрос по реализации движка приложения

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть набор библиотек классов и каждая из них должна отсылать движку собранную информацию (например, у меня есть FileSystemMonitor, основанный на FileSystemWatcher, только следящий за всей файловой системой). И вот есть вопрос, каким образом надо написать движок, чтобы передать информацию о состоянии компонента(ну например написав функцию ENGINE_TRACE), исключениях, событиях,чтоб он мог их обработать? Была идея такая: создать глобальный List<> в движке, и при вызове статического метода ENGINE_TRACE() записывать переданное в List<>. Так же и с событиями, т.е в классе движка располагаются события, на них подписываются компоненты и при событии все так же записывается в глобальный лист. Но я боюсь, что получится,пардон, говнокод. Можете,пожалуйста, что-нибудь посоветовать в плане реализации?

Comment: что значит движок? Какие задачи он решает? Вы игру пишете, веб сайт или что?

Comment: @tym32167 грубо говоря, он нужен для того, чтобы легко добавлять новые компоненты и поддерживать старые. задачи на нем висят следующие : сбор информации со всех компонентов программы и обработка их.

Comment: @tym32167 это windows приложение, в нем есть компоненты, которые собирают информацию, и мне нужно организовать каким-то образом в движке, чтобы обрабатывать информацию со всех компонентов (в т.ч исключения)

Comment: windows приложение на чем написанное? На Winforms? WPF? Готовые фреймворки смотрели или сами сразу пишете?

Comment: @tym32167 давайте я вам честно признаюсь - делаю немного экзотическую вещь - антивирус, с монитором процессов, реестра, файловой системы, немного проактивной защиты, эвристика. Многое написано через WinAPI, точнее то, что нет в .NET Framework. Фреймворки не смотрел, их просто нет. Поэтому решил написать свое.

Comment: @tym32167 и вот мне для этого и нужен движок, чтобы собирать всю информацию с компонентом, подгружать новые модули для АВ. Вот я и думаю, каким образом это написать. Точнее есть вариант, но я не уверен, что это нормальное решение (как я и писал выше)

Comment: @tym32167 GUI - Windows Forms, сервис - Windows Service. Сначала загружается стартер движка, который запускает компоненты, а вот потом на сам движок приходит инфа с компонентов.

Comment: Если вопрос в организации модулей приложения - то фреймворки есть, хоть [PRISM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx), хоть [MEF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/). Если вас интересуют общие подходы - как реализовывать блоки - есть [Enterprise Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff648951.aspx) от команды [Patterns & Practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921345.aspx) Майкрософта, у них и [руководство](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921343.aspx) есть по написанию настольных приложений.

Comment: @tym32167 а выше приведенный мною ( в вопросе ) способ не очень хороший? хотя бы примерную оценку

Comment: я дальше `создать глобальный List<>` читать не стал, так как у меня  ощущение, что вы не понимаете, как и что должно работать. Если бы вы меня о таком спросили, то я бы говорил о абстракциях, а не о реализациях (уже молчу о том, что глобальный `List<>` не потокобезопасный и не восстановится после сбоя приложентия)

Comment: Если говорить об абстрациях, я бы выделил клиентов, регистратора, шину передачи данных и хранилище (это первый взгляд). Клиент регистрируется у регистратора и передает ему данные по шине передачи данных. Регистратор принимает сообщения от клиентов и выполняет какую то логику, например, сохраняет сообщения в хранилище.

Comment: Фишка таких абстракций в том, что если вы эти абстракции проектируете правильно, то вам в итоге останется только их реализовать. Причем абстракции от реализаций не должны зависеть, то есть реализации хранилища абсолютно фиолетово, как реализованы регистратор или клиенты

Comment: например, сегодня вы передаете сообщения от клиента регистратору через простую шину в памяти (например, через прокси объект или аггрегатор событий), а завтра у вас кластер клиентов передает сообщения регистратору по шине передачи данных типа MSMQ или RabbitMQ и всё продолжает работать как прежде. А послезавтра вы хранилице в памяти меняете на БД и всё также будет работать

Comment: @tym32167 да, вы правы - я действительно не понимаю. есть компоненты, а вот как собирать информацию не знаю. Я подумал сделать так: сервис запускает через мой класс ComponentManager компоненты (то есть через него можно управлять остановкой\запуском компонентов), класс передает им eventhandler'ы, что и как нужно делать.Насчет лога - просто MemoryMappedFile и отправка на сервер (для дебага). GUI и Service соединены через NamedPipe.

Comment: @tym32167 А вы, кстати, правы... ведь действительно - запускаем компоненты и сам движок, компоненты через какую-нибудь NamedPipe соединяю, передаю движку данные, он их обрабатывает и т.п. И не надо никаких глобальных List<>.

Comment: Кстати, если вы планируете писать агентов, которые общаются через процессы, то поглядите в сторону [akka.net](https://getakka.net/)